# Both instruments in unison or only the first-voice one?

Tags: notation

Here are a few first measures of "Pomp and Circumstance, March 1"'s score:
[image]
What puzzles me is that in both the oboe and clarinet staves, we can clearly see two instruments indicated, yet there are instances where only one note is specified. Should this note be played by the higher-voiced instrument indicated on the staff, or should it be understood that, in these instances, the same note is to be played in unison by both instruments?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148796/discussion-on-question-by-brilliant-both-instruments-in-unison-or-only-the-first); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes are played by both instruments unless it's explicitly specified that only one is to play by marking the part *solo*, or *1.* or *2.* (or *I.* or *II.*)
It's quite likely the parts are printed so that each player has a separate part.

Answer (score 3):

If one staff only gives one voice it is usually played by all instruments, unless it is specifically marked *solo* or something like *I* or *II*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what usually is called a *condensed score*. The purpose is to give the conductor a score with fewer staves in order make it easier to read when performing. Instead of two staves for as example the two oboe parts it only shows one combined stave. Each oboe than has its own part with its own notes.

My guess here is that the copier making the condensed score was a bit inaccurate. Some details were probably missed. For example, the last note of bar 2 for clarinets should probably have a marcato articulation ^ but the copier has not indicated that -- every wind instrument part has a marcato there. Compare bar 2 and 4, where bar 4 to my eyes has better notation. Remember that in the old days, every note was painstakingly typeset by hand and sometimes inconsistencies did occur. Nowadays, you simply ask your note writing program to create the condensed score (at least on programs where that is automated).

Comment: This is not a condensed score.  It has never been standard practice for a full score to show every wind instrument on a separate staff.

Comment: @phoog I disagree,  it is a condensed score as each wind instrument gets its own part, but not its own staff in the score. In this respect the parts look different from the staff in the score, as two parts are condensed to one staff.  I agree that the standard practice for orchestral scores is to show the wind instruments condensed but there examples in the literature that differ. As a sidenote, at least one modern note writing program, Dorico, allows an automatic display of condensed score from separate parts without extra steps.